# How extract all URLs in a website using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, url, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I'm working on a project that require to extract all links from a website,
with using this code I'll get all of links from single URL:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer

source_code = requests.get('https://stackoverflow.com/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(source_code.content, 'lxml')
links = []

for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    links.append(str(link))
```

problem is that if I want to extract all URLs, I have to write another for loop and then another one ... .
I want to extract all URLs that are exist in this website and in this website's sub domains.
is there any way to do this without writing nested for?
and even with writing nested for, I don't know how many for should I use to get all URLs.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [retrieve links from web page using python and BeautifulSoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080411/retrieve-links-from-web-page-using-python-and-beautifulsoup)

Comment: No,it's not.
Also the answer of this question are no longer works because the BeautifulSoup changed since then.

Comment: @Mona well so you will need to use `API` of stackoverflow.

Comment: it's second time that you did guys delete you answers, :(((

Comment: I need a algorithm that work on every websites.

Comment: Do you just want URL's that start with https://www.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: @Mona actually we just read your question as crawling webpage. not the full url. anyway, what you looking for is a full crawler of website. so you need infinite loop which will never break till your memory boom. it's will keep get each url then open each url and collect links and so on.

Comment: Can you clarify what you’re trying to do? After reading @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη comment I’m no longer certain that I understand.

Comment: @AlexanderCécile she's looking to getting each single url inside website. `I want to extract all URLs that are exist in this website and in this website's sub domains.`

Comment: @oppressionslayer I need all URLs inside of my URL and all of my sub URLs too not only the sub URL.

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃ-αмєяιcαη my target website have limited URLs inside of it

Comment: @Mona What do you mean by _all of my sub URLs too not only the sub URL_? In any case, this sounds like web crawling, not web scraping.

Comment: We might still be able to help, if you can provide more details. You want only the URLs on this single domain?

Comment: @alexander-cécile yeah, your right, its web crawling not web scraping,
now how Can I do that?

Comment: Related/possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1080411/11301900

Answer (score 6, accepted):

WoW, it takes about 30 min to find a solution,
I found a **simple and efficient** way to do this,
As @αԋɱҽԃ-αмєяιcαη mentioned, some time if your website linked to a BIG website like google, etc, it wont be stop until you memory get full of data.
so there are steps that you should consider.

1. make a while loop to seek thorough your website to extract all of urls
2. use Exceptions handling to prevent crashes
3. remove duplicates and separate the urls
4. set a limitation to number of urls, like when 1000 urls found
5. stop while loop to prevent your PC's memory getting full

here a sample code and it should works fine, I actually tested it and it was fun fore me:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import time

source_code = requests.get('https://stackoverflow.com/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(source_code.content, 'lxml')
data = []
links = []


def remove_duplicates(l): # remove duplicates and unURL string
    for item in l:
        match = re.search("(?P<url>https?://[^\s]+)", item)
        if match is not None:
            links.append((match.group("url")))


for link in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
    data.append(str(link.get('href')))
flag = True
remove_duplicates(data)
while flag:
    try:
        for link in links:
            for j in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
                temp = []
                source_code = requests.get(link)
                soup = BeautifulSoup(source_code.content, 'lxml')
                temp.append(str(j.get('href')))
                remove_duplicates(temp)

                if len(links) > 162: # set limitation to number of URLs
                    break
            if len(links) > 162:
                break
        if len(links) > 162:
            break
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        if len(links) > 162:
            break

for url in links:
print(url)
```

and the output will be:

```
https://stackoverflow.com
https://www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/talent
https://www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/advertising
https://stackoverflow.com/users/login?ssrc=head&returnurl=https%3a%2f%2fstackoverflow.com%2f
https://stackoverflow.com/users/signup?ssrc=head&returnurl=%2fusers%2fstory%2fcurrent
https://stackoverflow.com
https://stackoverflow.com
https://stackoverflow.com/help
https://chat.stackoverflow.com
https://meta.stackoverflow.com
https://stackoverflow.com/users/signup?ssrc=site_switcher&returnurl=%2fusers%2fstory%2fcurrent
https://stackoverflow.com/users/login?ssrc=site_switcher&returnurl=https%3a%2f%2fstackoverflow.com%2f
https://stackexchange.com/sites
https://stackoverflow.blog
https://stackoverflow.com/legal/cookie-policy
https://stackoverflow.com/legal/privacy-policy
https://stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service/public
https://stackoverflow.com/teams
https://stackoverflow.com/teams
https://www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/talent
https://www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/advertising
https://www.g2.com/products/stack-overflow-for-teams/
https://www.g2.com/products/stack-overflow-for-teams/
https://www.fastcompany.com/most-innovative-companies/2019/sectors/enterprise
https://www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/talent
https://www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/advertising
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55884514/what-is-the-incentive-for-curl-to-release-the-library-for-free/55885729#55885729
https://insights.stackoverflow.com/
https://stackoverflow.com
https://stackoverflow.com
https://stackoverflow.com/jobs
https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/directory/developer-jobs
https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/salary
https://www.stackoverflowbusiness.com
https://stackoverflow.com/teams
https://www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/talent
https://www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/advertising
https://stackoverflow.com/enterprise
https://stackoverflow.com/company/about
https://stackoverflow.com/company/about
https://stackoverflow.com/company/press
https://stackoverflow.com/company/work-here
https://stackoverflow.com/legal
https://stackoverflow.com/legal/privacy-policy
https://stackoverflow.com/company/contact
https://stackexchange.com
https://stackoverflow.com
https://serverfault.com
https://superuser.com
https://webapps.stackexchange.com
https://askubuntu.com
https://webmasters.stackexchange.com
https://gamedev.stackexchange.com
https://tex.stackexchange.com
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com
https://unix.stackexchange.com
https://apple.stackexchange.com
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com
https://gis.stackexchange.com
https://electronics.stackexchange.com
https://android.stackexchange.com
https://security.stackexchange.com
https://dba.stackexchange.com
https://drupal.stackexchange.com
https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com
https://ux.stackexchange.com
https://mathematica.stackexchange.com
https://salesforce.stackexchange.com
https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com
https://pt.stackoverflow.com
https://blender.stackexchange.com
https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com
https://crypto.stackexchange.com
https://codereview.stackexchange.com
https://magento.stackexchange.com
https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com
https://dsp.stackexchange.com
https://emacs.stackexchange.com
https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com
https://ru.stackoverflow.com
https://codegolf.stackexchange.com
https://es.stackoverflow.com
https://ethereum.stackexchange.com
https://datascience.stackexchange.com
https://arduino.stackexchange.com
https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com
https://sqa.stackexchange.com
https://sound.stackexchange.com
https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com
https://stackexchange.com/sites#technology
https://photo.stackexchange.com
https://scifi.stackexchange.com
https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com
https://movies.stackexchange.com
https://music.stackexchange.com
https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com
https://video.stackexchange.com
https://cooking.stackexchange.com
https://diy.stackexchange.com
https://money.stackexchange.com
https://academia.stackexchange.com
https://law.stackexchange.com
https://fitness.stackexchange.com
https://gardening.stackexchange.com
https://parenting.stackexchange.com
https://stackexchange.com/sites#lifearts
https://english.stackexchange.com
https://skeptics.stackexchange.com
https://judaism.stackexchange.com
https://travel.stackexchange.com
https://christianity.stackexchange.com
https://ell.stackexchange.com
https://japanese.stackexchange.com
https://chinese.stackexchange.com
https://french.stackexchange.com
https://german.stackexchange.com
https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com
https://history.stackexchange.com
https://spanish.stackexchange.com
https://islam.stackexchange.com
https://rus.stackexchange.com
https://russian.stackexchange.com
https://gaming.stackexchange.com
https://bicycles.stackexchange.com
https://rpg.stackexchange.com
https://anime.stackexchange.com
https://puzzling.stackexchange.com
https://mechanics.stackexchange.com
https://boardgames.stackexchange.com
https://bricks.stackexchange.com
https://homebrew.stackexchange.com
https://martialarts.stackexchange.com
https://outdoors.stackexchange.com
https://poker.stackexchange.com
https://chess.stackexchange.com
https://sports.stackexchange.com
https://stackexchange.com/sites#culturerecreation
https://mathoverflow.net
https://math.stackexchange.com
https://stats.stackexchange.com
https://cstheory.stackexchange.com
https://physics.stackexchange.com
https://chemistry.stackexchange.com
https://biology.stackexchange.com
https://cs.stackexchange.com
https://philosophy.stackexchange.com
https://linguistics.stackexchange.com
https://psychology.stackexchange.com
https://scicomp.stackexchange.com
https://stackexchange.com/sites#science
https://meta.stackexchange.com
https://stackapps.com
https://api.stackexchange.com
https://data.stackexchange.com
https://stackoverflow.blog?blb=1
https://www.facebook.com/officialstackoverflow/
https://twitter.com/stackoverflow
https://linkedin.com/company/stack-overflow
https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/
https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/06/25/attribution-required/
https://stackoverflow.com
https://www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/talent
https://www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/advertising

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I set the limitation to 162, you can increase it as many as you want and you ram allowed.

Comment: thank you so much.
you saved my day :)
long and a little dirty code, but it works fine as you said.

Comment: Wait what’s up with `remove_duplicates()`?! Why not just extract the url and put it in a set?

Comment: @alexander-cécile yeah,my code is nasty,I'm a little bit busy so I  will edit it tomorrow,
and about checking `if len(links) > 162`, I did this to check this condition after every step and I know it's not necessary.

Comment: @alexander-cécile if you have extra time, I will be glad if you edit my answer, other wise I will edit it latter.

Comment: @Ali I think I’ll make a separate answer, because I plan on using a different library entirely.

Comment: @alexander-cécile glad to hear it, can't waiting to learn new way to do this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204312/discussion-between-ali-and-alexander-cecile).

Answer (score 0):

How's this?

```
import re,requests
from simplified_scrapy.simplified_doc import SimplifiedDoc 
source_code = requests.get('https://stackoverflow.com/')
doc = SimplifiedDoc(source_code.content.decode('utf-8')) # incoming HTML string
lst = doc.listA(url='https://stackoverflow.com/') # get all links
for a in lst:
  if(a['url'].find('stackoverflow.com')>0): #sub domains
    print (a['url'])
```

You can also use this crawl frame, which can help you do many things

```
from simplified_scrapy.spider import Spider, SimplifiedDoc
class DemoSpider(Spider):
  name = 'demo-spider'
  start_urls = ['http://www.example.com/']
  allowed_domains = ['example.com/']
  def extract(self, url, html, models, modelNames):
    doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
    lstA = doc.listA(url=url["url"])
    return [{"Urls": lstA, "Data": None}]

from simplified_scrapy.simplified_main import SimplifiedMain
SimplifiedMain.startThread(DemoSpider())
```

Answer (score 0):

I implemented this for my task and it was able to extract all the URLs from all the pages and pages inside the pages. This is a recursive function.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

url = "https://stackoverflow.com"
df = pd.DataFrame()
links = []
def extract_links(url):
    print("source url",url)
    global links
    source_url = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(source_url.content,"html.parser")
    for link in soup.find_all('a',href=True):
        try:
            if len(links) >=100:
                return
            if link.get('href').startswith("https://") and link.get("href") not in links:
                links.append(link.get('href'))
                extract_links(link.get('href'))

        except Exception as e:
            print("Unhandled exception",e)

extract_links(url)
df = pd.DataFrame({"links":links})
df.to_csv("links.csv")
```

Let me explain how it works:

1. It will go into the first page: stackoverflow.com and the link will be appended in links list.
2. Any link inside main page will be passed as the URL parameter to the function. This way it will fetch all the url/links inside the all the pages and will be appended in the links list. This helps to avoid any repeatition of links.
3. If there is no link to fetch, it will come back to the main page and fetch the second link and will recursively move inside all the pages inside the link.
4. Finally, when there is no more link to parse, all the links will be stored in a dataframe.

Answer (score -1):

Well, actually what you are asking for is possible but that's mean an infinite loop which will keep run and run till your memory `BoOoOoOm`

Anyway the idea should be like the following.

- you will use `for item in soup.findAll('a')` and `then
  item.get('href')`
- add to `set` to get rid of duplicates urls and use with `if`
  condition `is not None` to get rid of `None` objects.
- then keep looping over and over till your `set` became `0` something
  like `len(urls)`

Comment: It's not the answer of my question, 
for instance there is over 10,000,000 questions in stackoverflow,
I need a code that extract all of existence URLs include the URLs of all of stackoverflow's post and etc.

Comment: can you give me a code to know to how implement this idea?

Comment: @Mona that's will need you to implement this by yourself. because you will need to use `try/except` and `timeout` and `threading`.. many things ! what if the `href` hold a path of `url` such as `/file1/file2/` so that's will need `f` string. to be like `f"www.site.com/{url}"` and too many others things which need to dev him/her self to be focus on.

Comment: @Mona What are you using all this for?

Comment: I agree with @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη though, this is a rather large question.

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃ-αмєяιcαη I'm a new  member of stackoverflow, 
some body answered my question very well,
my question wasn't based on opinion, it was just a question that you weren't able to help.

Comment: @Mona if you have taken time to what I’ve typed so you will not see difference. But anyway feel free to think as you want . We’ve used to deal with such comments

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη I google about ram usage about this question,
with 12 GB of ram you are able to store about 128849018 URL (100 character per url)  in your ram as a variable,
so I think it won't be a problem.

Comment: @Ali you need to understand the difference between RAM and Storage.

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη I know the difference

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη run the code and look at you ram usage,
with about 10000 link scraped, my ram barley moved.

Comment: @Ali well so you will be forever running your program and waiting for it to finish. since you are talking about for loop running without threads which use only  one variable like a rat which keep run and stop. but with threads the scenario will be different.